# Oracle alter table references

Tags: oracle

I am new with oracle. I create a simple table which is i refer from a note

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
employee_id NUMBER(6),
first_name VARCHAR2(20),
last_name VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT emp_lname_nn NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT emp_email_nn NOT NULL,
phone_number VARCHAR2(20),
hire_date DATE CONSTRAINT emp_hdate_nn NOT NULL,
job_id VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT emp_job_nn NOT NULL,
salary NUMBER(8,2),
commission_pct NUMBER(2,2),
manager_id NUMBER(6),
department_id NUMBER(4),
CONSTRAINT emp_salary_min CHECK (salary > 0),
CONSTRAINT emp_email_uk UNIQUE (email)
) ;
```

Then tried to alter the table to adds integrity constraints to the employees table. Integrity constraints enforce business rules and prevent the entry of invalid information into tables.

```
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD (CONSTRAINT emp_emp_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
CONSTRAINT emp_dept_fk FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
REFERENCES departments,
CONSTRAINT emp_job_fk FOREIGN KEY (job_id)
REFERENCES jobs (job_id),
CONSTRAINT emp_manager_fk FOREIGN KEY (manager_id)
REFERENCES employees
) ;
```

But then i got an error

> REFERENCES departments,
>              * ERROR at line 4: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I check the note, they said nothing about create departments tables. They just show how to create employees tables.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The error cleary says DEPARTMENTS table is missing... The below foreign key constratint referencing the department_id column of departments table.

CONSTRAINT emp_dept_fk FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
REFERENCES departments

So create the departments table with department_id column and also to add below constraint you need to create a jobs table with job_id column...

CONSTRAINT emp_job_fk FOREIGN KEY (job_id)
REFERENCES jobs (job_id),